# How to align labels in cross bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to align three text labels i.e. mean, median and current value outside the crossbars.I appreciate any help.

**My Data**

```
structure(list(variable = structure(1:10, .Label = c("GrossNetEquity", 
"GrossTotalEquityPerfAttr", "LongNetEquity", "LongTotalEquity", 
"NetEquity", "NetEquityPerfAttr", "NetTotalEquity", "ShortNetEquity", 
"ShortTotalEquity", "TotalNetEquity"), class = "factor"), mx = c(134.5, 
8.1, 95.6, 106.4, 61, 6.8, 71.6, -21.4, -24.9, 148.7), mn = c(71.1, 
-4.6, 49.7, 66.2, 27, -4.1, 36.4, -46.3, -47.4, 96), avg = c(112.173148148148, 
1.14814814814815, 77.7388888888889, 84.5111111111111, 43.262037037037, 
1.05092592592593, 48.0694444444444, -34.4194444444444, -36.4416666666667, 
120.952777777778), sd = c(14.5968093202928, 2.39877232936504, 
9.87368667081958, 8.7204382695887, 7.29159953981859, 2.24405738054356, 
7.05196278547511, 6.04899711056417, 5.77265751334298, 13.0003483658092
), md = c(114.15, 1.4, 77.35, 82.65, 41.45, 1.25, 46.35, -34.1, 
-35.55, 119.75), firstldiff = c(82.9795295075625, -3.64939651058193, 
57.9915155472497, 67.0702345719337, 28.6788379573998, -3.4371888351612, 
33.9655188734942, -46.5174386655728, -47.9869816933526, 94.9520810461593
), firstlsum = c(141.366766788734, 5.94569280687823, 97.4862622305281, 
101.951987650289, 57.8452361166742, 5.53904068701305, 62.1733700153947, 
-22.3214502233161, -24.8963516399807, 146.953474509396), secldiff = c(68.3827201872697, 
-6.04816883994697, 48.1178288764302, 58.349796302345, 21.3872384175813, 
-5.68124621570476, 26.9135560880191, -52.566435776137, -53.7596392066956, 
81.9517326803501), seclsum = c(155.963576109027, 8.34446513624327, 
107.359948901348, 110.672425919877, 65.1368356564928, 7.78309806755661, 
69.2253328008698, -16.2724531127519, -19.1236941266377, 159.953822875205
), value = c(116.1, -1.2, 88, 92.3, 58.8, -1.2, 63, -28.1, -29.3, 
121.6), Criteria = c(NA, NA, "", "", "orange", "", "orange", 
"orange", "", "orange")), .Names = c("variable", "mx", "mn", 
"avg", "sd", "md", "firstldiff", "firstlsum", "secldiff", "seclsum", 
"value", "Criteria"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**My Code** 
I am trying to show Mean, Median and Current Value in the form of bars on geom_crossbar.But finding it hard to align it.

```
ggplot(df3,aes(variable,mn))+
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = mn, ymax = mx,fill = Criteria),
                width = 0.5,alpha = 0.50,position =position_dodge())+
  geom_point(data=df3, aes(x=variable,y=md,group=1),
             shape = "|", size = 10,color ="brown1")+
  geom_text(data=df3, aes(x=variable, y=md, label = paste("Median",md)), 
            size = 3, vjust = 2,hjust = -1.0,color = "brown1",
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9))+
  geom_point(data=df3, aes(x=variable,y=avg,group=1),
             shape = "|", size = 10,color = "coral4")+
  geom_text(data=df3, aes(x=variable, y=avg, label = paste("Mean",mn)),
            size = 3, vjust = 2.5, hjust = -1.0,color ="coral4")+
  geom_point(data=df3, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=1),
             shape = "|", size = 10,color ="brown1")+
  geom_text(data=df3,aes(x=variable, y=value,label = paste("Current Value",value)), 
            size = 2, vjust = 3, hjust = -1.0,color = "brown1")+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Can you add the result to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to align your `geom_text` layers, you can assign them the same y value. I've included an example below. I also removed some repetitive parts from your code, where the different layers can inherit the data / aesthetic mappings from the top `ggplot()` level.

```
ggplot(df3, aes(variable, mx))+

  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = mn, ymax = mx, fill = Criteria),
                width = 0.5, alpha = 0.50, position = position_dodge()) +

  # vertical bars
  geom_point(aes(y = md), shape = "|", size = 10, color ="brown1") +
  geom_point(aes(y = avg), shape = "|", size = 10, color = "coral4") +
  geom_point(aes(y = value), shape = "|", size = 10, color ="brown1") +

  # labels (vjust used to move the three layers vertically away from one another; 
  # nudge_y used to shift them uniformly rightwards)
  # note that the original label for "Mean" used paste("Mean", mn), but that didn't
  # look right to me, since the vertical bar above used avg instead of mn, & mn appears
  # to correspond to "min", not "mean".
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Median", md)),
            size = 3, vjust = -1, nudge_y = 5, hjust = 0, color = "brown1") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Mean", avg)),
            size = 3, vjust = 0, nudge_y = 5, hjust = 0, color ="coral4") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Current Value", value)),
            size = 2, vjust = 1, nudge_y = 5, hjust = 0, color = "brown1") +

  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(y = 200) # expand rightwards to give more space for labels
```

[image: plot]

*Note*: The above follows the approach in your code, which repeats the same geom layers for different columns in the wide format data. In general, ggplot prefers to deal with data in *long* format. It looks cleaner, and would be easier to maintain as you only need to make changes (e.g. increase font size, change number of decimal places in the label) once, rather than repeat the change for every affected layer. A long format approach to this problem could look like this:

```
# create long format data frame for labels
df3.labels <- df3 %>%
  select(variable, mx, md, avg, value) %>%
  tidyr::gather(type, value, -variable, -mx) %>%
  mutate(label = paste0(case_when(type == "md" ~ "Median",
                                  type == "avg" ~ "Mean",
                                  TRUE ~ "Current Value"),
                        ": ",
                        round(value, 2)),
         vjust = case_when(type == "md" ~ -1,
                           type == "avg" ~ 0,
                           TRUE ~ 1))

# place df3.labels in the top level call, since there are two geom layers that 
# use it as the data source, & only one that uses df3.
ggplot(df3.labels,
       aes(x = variable, y = value, color = type, label = label)) +  
  geom_crossbar(data = df3, 
                aes(x = variable, y = mn, ymin = mn, ymax = mx, fill = Criteria),
                inherit.aes = FALSE,
                width = 0.5, alpha = 0.50) +  
  geom_point(shape = "|", size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(y = mx, vjust = vjust), size = 3, nudge_y = 5, hjust = 0) +

  # change colour mappings here
  scale_color_manual(values = c("md" = "brown1", "avg" = "coral4", "value" = "brown1"),
                     guide = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(y = 200)
```

Comment: Thank you.. Being new it was great help